# How can I inject services into my entity bundle class?

Tags: entities

I have an entity with a JSON field, and I do some complicated processing when the entity is saved.

Right now, I do this processing in `hook_ENTITY_presave()`, which calls a service I have created in a custom module.

However, since Drupal 9.3, we can [create bundle classes](https://www.drupal.org/node/3191609) to extend entities cleanly.

So I made one for my entity, and I wrote some new getters and setters so I can do `$entity->getMyValue()` instead of `$entity->field_abc->value`.

Now, I want to take the next step and inject my service into the entity and move the processing directly into the entity on save.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, this is not yet possible.  There is a [discussion in the Core issue queue on how to proceed with this.](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2142515)

As noted in the discussion linked above, an alternative to do this now is to use the [Typed Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/typed_entity), which wraps entities into objects and allows you to do dependency injection.